# Realizar um split em whois utilizando expressão regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho um response com whois.

Gostaria de realizar um `split` pegando os valores após o `<br />` até o final da linha do whois.

Por exemplo: na linha `<br />person: Ana Flavia Miziara`, eu quero somente o valor **person: Ana Flavia Miziara**. Estou fazendo isso através de uma planilha. 1 célula contem o whois, vou utilizar JS para fazer um script que lê o whois na célula, utilizar regex para fazer o `split` e jogar o valor X em outra célula.

Vou colocar um exemplo abaixo do whois:

```
{"whois":
"<br />% Copyright (c) Nic.br<br />%  The use of the data below is only permitted as described in
<br />%  full by the terms of use at https://registro.br/termo/en.html ,
<br />%  being prohibited its distribution, commercialization or
<br />%  reproduction, in particular, to use it for advertising or
<br />%  any similar purpose.
<br />%  2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00
<br />
<br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br
<br />owner:       BMGV Music Software Net Editora Ltda.
<br />ownerid:     66.587.684/0001-88
<br />responsible: Ana Flavia Miziara
<br />country:     BR
<br />owner-c:     AFM3
<br />admin-c:     AFM3
<br />tech-c:      AFM3
<br />billing-c:   AFM3
<br />nserver:     ns1.locaweb.com.br
<br />nsstat:      20190304 TIMEOUT
<br />nslastaa:    20190301
<br />nserver:     ns2.locaweb.com.br
<br />nsstat:      20190304 AA
<br />nslastaa:    20190304
<br />created:     20000421 #322333
<br />changed:     20180330
<br />expires:     20190421
<br />status:      published
<br />
<br />nic-hdl-br:  AFM3
<br />person:      Ana Flavia Miziara
<br />e-mail:      bmgv@uol.com.br
<br />country:     BR
<br />created:     19980128
<br />changed:     20031218
<br />
<br />% Security and mail abuse issues should also be addressed to
<br />% cert.br, http://www.cert.br/ , respectivelly to cert@cert.br
<br />% and mail-abuse@cert.br
<br />%
<br />% whois.registro.br accepts only direct match queries. Types
<br />% of queries are: domain (.br), registrant (tax ID), ticket,
<br />% provider, contact handle (ID), CIDR block, IP and ASN.
<br />","error":false}
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem ? Qual o resultado que espera obter ? O que vai fazer com esse resultado ?

Comment: Estou usando java script, quero obter o resultado de cada linha por exemplo: person:      Ana Flavia Miziara, e eu vou alimentar um banco de dados com esses valores.

Comment: Se fizer um `split` pelo `<br>` você já obtem todas as linhas, mas algo me diz que só está interessada em algumas, e num formato especifico

Comment: é esse o porem, eu quero remover os <br /> e pegar o valor que vem depois. Por exemplo: na linha <br />person:      Ana Flavia Miziara, eu quero somente o valor person:      Ana Flavia Miziara. 
Estou fazendo isso através de uma planilha. 1 célula contem o whois, vou utilizar JS para fazer um script que lê o whois na célula, utiliza regex para fazer o split e joga o valor X em outra célula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementando a [resposta do Andrei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367973/112052), seguem algumas alternativas (considerando o caso em que toda a string está em uma linha só):

```js
let str = '2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00<br /><br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br<br />expires:     20190421<br /><br />country:     BR';

let regex = /<br \/>([\w-]+):\s*([^<]+)/gi;
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(str)) { // match[1] é o nome do campo, match[2] é o valor
  console.log(`${match[1]} = ${match[2]}`);
}
```

A regex é bem parecida:

- começa com `<br />` (sendo que a barra deve ser escapada com `\` para não ser confundida com o delimitador da regex)
- `[\w-]+` é "uma ou mais ocorrências de `\w` (letras, números e o caractere `_`) ou hífen"
- `:\s*`: dois-pontos, seguido de zero ou mais espaços
- `[^<]+`: aqui está a diferença. Em vez de `.` (que significa "qualquer caractere"), eu usei uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). No caso, tudo que está entre `[^` e `]` é negado, ou seja, isso significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere **que não seja** `<`". Isso garante que eu pego todos os caracteres até a próxima tag

Se fosse um HTML mais complexo eu colocaria mais alguns controles na regex - ou [usaria um parser de HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) mesmo - mas como eu "sei" que a string só tem `<br />` (na verdade estou assumindo que ela tem o formato indicado na pergunta, portanto não tem nenhuma outra tag), posso usar `[^<]+` sem problemas.

Usando `.+` não funciona porque o quantificador `+` é [ganancioso](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tenta pegar a maior quantidade de caracteres possível ([veja um exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/Mvyarf/1/)). E como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, ele acaba pegando inclusive outras tags `<br />`. Já usando `[^<]+` eu garanto que a regex vai parar quando encontrar alguma tag ([veja um exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/ZYJqL4/1/)) - e como estou assumindo que não existem outras tags além do `br`, é o suficiente para que funcione.

*Na verdade, o comportamento padrão do ponto é pegar qualquer caractere [**exceto as quebras de linha**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions), é por isso que usar `.+` funciona quando há quebras de linha na string (aliás, se usar `[^<]`, também vai funcionar quando há quebras de linha).*

Sendo assim, a regex pega tudo após um `<br />`, até encontrar o próximo.

Só um detalhe quanto a `[\w-]+`. O `\w` é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para "letras de `A` a `Z` (maiúsculas ou minúsculas), números de 0 a 9 ou o caractere `_`", então `[\w-]+` aceita strings como `---_1`, por exemplo ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/x1Qmzz/1/)).

Como a string possui um formato que parece ser bem definido, pode ser que estas situações estranhas nunca ocorram, mas se quiser ser mais específico, pode usar algo como `[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*` (letras, seguidas de zero ou mais "hífen seguido de letras"). Isso garante que os nomes como `domain` e `nic-hdl-br` sejam aceitos, mas `---_1` não ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/x1Qmzz/2/)).

E como a regex usa a opção `i` (veja depois da barra que tem `gi`), ela considera tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minúsculas (mas pode tirar o `i` se só quiser minúsculas, por exemplo, e usar `[a-z0-9]` se quiser também números).

Então ficaria assim:

```js
let str = '2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00<br /><br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br<br />expires:     20190421<br /><br />country:     BR';

let regex = /<br \/>([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*):\s*([^<]+)/gi;
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(str)) { // match[1] é o nome do campo, match[2] é o valor
  console.log(`${match[1]} = ${match[2]}`);
}
```

Repare que usei `(?:`, que faz com que os parênteses sejam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Se tivesse somente `(`, eles formariam outro grupo, interferindo nos grupos já existentes (`match[2]` passaria a ser `match[3]`, já que agora seriam 3 pares de parênteses). Como este é um grupo que não quero capturar, eu uso a sintaxe de não-captura, e os grupos já existentes permanecem intactos.

---

#### `split`

Outra alternativa é usar [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), para a qual também forneço uma alternativa:

```js
let str = '2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00<br /><br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br<br />expires:     20190421<br /><br />country:     BR';
str.split(/(?:<br \/>)+/i).forEach(element => {
    let v = element.split(/:\s*/); // v[0] é o nome do campo, v[1] é o valor
    if (v.length == 2) console.log(`${v[0]} = ${v[1]}`);
});
```

A diferença para a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367973/112052) é que usei `(?:<br \/>)+`: uma ou mais ocorrências de `<br />`. Eu tive que usar `(?:` para fazer com que os parênteses sejam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Se eu não fizesse isso (e usasse parênteses simples, como `(<br \/>)+`), os grupos de captura [seriam incluídos no resultado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516064) (ou seja, o array resultante teria os `<br />` dentro dele também). Também usei a opção `i` para o caso de ter uma tag `<BR />`, por exemplo (se você tem certeza que sempre é `br` minúsculo, pode até tirar o `i`).

O `split` faz com que a string seja separada pelos `<br />`. Em seguida, para cada elemento eu faço outro `split`, para separar por "dois-pontos seguidos de zero ou mais espaços", para pegar o nome e valor de cada campo separadamente. Eu também testo se o resultado deste `split` é um array de tamanho 2, pois ao fazer `split` da data (`2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00`), o resultado é um array de 4 elementos (testando o tamanho do array eu já descarto boa parte desses falsos positivos).

Obviamente eu também poderia usar uma regex parecida com a anterior, mas sem o `<br />`, para extrair o nome e valor:

```js
let str = '2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00<br /><br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br<br />expires:     20190421<br /><br />country:     BR';
str.split(/(?:<br \/>)+/i).forEach(element => {
    let match = /([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*):\s*(.+)/.exec(element);
    if (match) console.log(`${match[1]} = ${match[2]}`);
});
```

Nesse caso usei o ponto em vez de `[^<]`, já que todas as ocorrências de `<br />` foram eliminadas pelo `split` (e estou assumindo que a string não tem outras tags).

Comment: Sabia que você não iria resistir.... XD Ótima resposta!

Answer (score 4):

Se for apenas os valores que tem os `:` (dois pontos) como:

```
person: Ana Flavia Miziara
```

Você pode pega-los usando esta REGEX:

```
<br \/>([\w-]+:\s*.+)
```

**O que significa essa REGEX:**

Inicio:

- `<br \/>` Identifica e inicia com esta tag

Grupo (a informação que você quer estará aqui):

- `[\w-]+` depois pega qualquer letra ou número com ou sem hífen
- `:` depois pega os 2 pontos uma vez apenas
- `\s*` pode haver espaços ou não
- `.+` pega tudo que vem depois em um grupo

E então, você pode usar da seguinte forma:

```js
var str = '{"whois":\n'+
'"<br />% Copyright (c) Nic.br<br />%  The use of the data below is only permitted as described in\n'+
'<br />%  full by the terms of use at https://registro.br/termo/en.html ,\n' +
'<br />%  being prohibited its distribution, commercialization or\n'+
'<br />%  reproduction, in particular, to use it for advertising or\n'+
'<br />%  any similar purpose.\n' +
'<br />%  2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00\n' +
'<br />\n'+
'<br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br\n'+
'<br />owner:       BMGV Music Software Net Editora Ltda.\n'+
'<br />responsible: Ana Flavia Miziara\n'+
'<br />country:     BR\n'+
'<br />owner-c:     AFM3\n';

var regex = /<br \/>([\w-]+:\s*.+)/gi;
match = regex.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  match = regex.exec(str);
}
```

Se houver mais informações que você precisa. O split `<br />` é a melhor maneira, como foi dito pelo @Isac.

**Conforme sugerido pelo @hkotsubo:**

Caso você precise dos valores separados, como:

```
"person" - "Ana Flavia Miziara"
```

Esta REGEX...

```
<br \/>([\w-]+):\s*(.+)
```

... irá separar os valores automaticamente. E você poderá usar da seguinte forma:

```
var regex = /<br \/>([\w-]+):\s*(.+)/gi;
match = regex.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1]); // valor "person" 
  console.log(match[2]); // valor "Ana Flavia Miziara" 
  match = regex.exec(str);
}
```

**Edição**

As regex anteriores não funcionam pois, diferente de como está mostrado na pergunta, a string não pula linhas. É uma linha apenas. O que torna mais difícil criar um regex para isso pois ele pega toda a linha após encontrar a primeira ocorrência de `<br />`.

A solução volta para o que o @Isac comentou que é usar o `split` para quebrar as linhas e recuperar os valores:

```js
var str = '2019-03-07T02:48:17-03:00<br /><br />domain:      100anosdemusica.com.br<br />expires:     20190421<br /><br />country:     BR';
var strArray = str.split("<br /><br />");
var elementsArray1 = strArray[1].split("<br />");
var elementsArray2 = strArray[2].split("<br />");
elementsArray1.forEach(function(element, index, array){
 console.log(element);
});
elementsArray2.forEach(function(element, index, array){
 console.log(element);
});
```

Mas se ainda sim, você preferir o regex, creio que este te atenda:

```
<br \/>([\w-]+:\s*[\/\w\.\-\#\s]+)
```

Ficando assim o código:

```
var regex = /<br \/>([\w-]+:\s*[\/\w\.\-\#\s]+)/gi;
var match = regex.exec(str);
while(match != null){
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(str);
}
```

> obs: O problema desta regex é que se houver algum caractere
>   inesperado, faltará informação na linha.

Comment: `{1}` não é necessário, `(qualquer-coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer-coisa)`  - veja como  [isso](https://regex101.com/r/WF4fkj/1/) é o mesmo que [isso](https://regex101.com/r/B9zeZR/1/). Uma sugestão é mudar para `<br \/>([\w-]+):\s*(.+)`, assim o grupo 1 (`match[1]`) será o nome do campo (domain, owner, etc) e o grupo 2 (`match[2]`) será o respectivo valor, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/WF4fkj/2/)

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigado! Vou editar e inserir da forma como você sugeriu! Na questão dos grupos, pelo que eu entendi... Ela quer tudo junto! Mas vou colocar essa versão separada caso ela precise.

Comment: Eu entendi que era pra pegar separado :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo pode ser que eu tenha entendido errado mesmo... =) ... Mas obrigado de qualquer forma!

Comment: @hkotsubo eu sabia que você viria! XD sorte que cheguei antes! Obrigado pelo +1

Comment: Haha, cheguei atrasado :-) Mas agora relendo a pergunta, fiquei em dúvida se era pra ser junto ou separado... De qualquer forma, ainda acho melhor separar, porque aí já elimina os espaços depois do `:`

Comment: @hkotsubo concordo! Mas fica ai uma opção a mais!

Comment: Olá Andrei, agradeço pela sua resposta! Porem, quando tento reproduzir ela, o regex ignora somente o primeiro <br />

Comment: @LeticiaFatima fiz uma edição. Na variável `str` coloque toda a string do `whois`

Comment: @LeticiaFatima fiz outra edição.

Comment: Não resisti e acabei colocando uma resposta :-)